# How to find where all the string key is used in android?

Tags: android, string, multilingual

I am working in a multi language project so want to find out where exactly the strings are used from the value name in the string file programatically so once I get the Ids of the widgets (i.e textview or spinner or any widgets) where the strings are used so I can set them at once.

We are actually giving an interface for the user to change the content (label) of the textview field of android in our website so wanna set them to the received from json at all the places in android application.

Please help!!! Tysm in advance!

Comment: use `Replace in path` in Edit - Find menu. Enter old ID to search and new ID to replace

Comment: do you really need to change the ID? or just the Value?

Comment: if it is multi language then contents are changed depending on the users language preference? and is dictated by a button or something?

Comment: I actually wanted to get the ids of the string used in various xml files programmatically so that I can  change  them programmatically at a single place if needed @Orvenito

Comment: Tysm for guiding me. but I actually wanted to do this programatically @VladMatvienko

Comment: can you explain why you need to change it since it's an ID?

Comment: You can't change layouts of your own app inside your app.

Comment: I am working in a multi language project so want to find out where exactly the strings are used from the value name in the string file so once I get the Ids of the widgets where the strings are used so I can set them at once. its like we are giving an interface for the user to change the content of the textview  field of android in our website so wanna set them to the received from json at all the places in android application @Orvenito

Comment: I dnt wanna change them I just wanna set the values after getting the the ids of widgets where those strings are used @VladMatvienko

Comment: there is no way to get, which string ID is used in the view. You will have to implement it on your own.

Comment: bro, you are making your job harder. why not create an exactly the same xml(layout) and then call it when you know the user wants a different language.

Comment: can I know what json data you are receiving to know what language to use?

Comment: You mean for each widget ID I need to set values individually?? @VladMatvienko

Comment: Actually I Have hardcoded the default values in different languages but if the user set a different label for that particular field in the website then i have to set that label of the textview in my application so for different user the text label will be different @Orvenito

Comment: it doesn't matter now. so whatever the user set for the field in the website that is what you should show in your app. no need for changing the ID's

Comment: I do not wanna change the IDs... I just want to know where the strings are used  so that I can change the values of that fields by somehow getting all the IDs where they are used @Orvenito

Comment: your json should be specific then: jsonstring1 = Label1, jsonstring2 = Label3, jsonstring = Textview1 etc..

Comment: JSON will be customised as per what I actually require but how can i get IDs where those strings are used?? @Orvenito

Comment: why it will be customised? you can't just get the ID when you know the json response is not always the same.

Comment: I want to get id from the string name of string resource file that is used in various layouts

Answer (score 1):

> I want to find out where the string values are used which is declared
>   in the string file in android.

Steps.

1) Go to your res folder > Values > strings.xml

2) Select the String which you need to look up in project.

3) right click > find usages ( Alt + F7)

4) In bottom find tab will appear with all the string usages through out the project and it will show the usage in Java and XML resources as well.

For your reference added the screenshot [image]

For replacing the text you can look into the @Anurag Pandit answer

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Android Studio. In that case you can right click the key of the string in the `strings.xml` file and select `Find usages`. This will show you a list of where the selected key is used.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Command + Shift + r` 
A popUp will appear, place your required *search* string in `"Text to find:"` 
and in **Scope** select `Whole project` .

You can see all the places where the string is used in `Preview` window before replacing it.

- [Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html) you could find a bunch of shortcuts for `Mac/Windows/Ubuntu` for faster development.